parse XML without using global variables
I want to parse this kind of XML using XSLT 1.0 only:
<root>
    <Block id="1" inputPorts="2" outputPorts="3" />
    <OutputPort id="2" parent="1" /> <!-- first OutputPort after Block so current = 0, should give coordinate(0,3) = 1/6 -->
    <InputPort id="3" parent="1" /> <!-- first InputPort after Block so current = 0, should give coordinate(0,2) = 1/4 -->
    <OutputPort id="4" parent="1" /> <!-- second OutputPort after Block so current = 1, should give coordinate(1,3) = 3/6 -->
    <InputPort id="5" parent="1" /> <!-- second InputPort after Block so current = 1, should give coordinate(1,2) = 3/4 -->
    <OutputPort id="6" parent="1" /> <!-- third OutputPort after Block so current = 2, should give coordinate(2,3) of 5/6 -->

    <Block id="7" inputPorts="0" outputPorts="1" />
    <OutputPort id="8" parent="7" /> <!-- first OutputPort after Block so current = 0, should give coordinate(0,1) = 1/2 -->
</root>

There are multple Block tags. InputPort and OutputPort tags follow in any order after the Block tag, as per number available in attributes of Block. However, they are before the next Block tag.
The output should be like this:
<root>
    <Block id="1" inputPorts="2" outputPorts="3" />
    <OutputPort id="2" parent="1" coordinate="0.1666" />
    <InputPort id="3" parent="1" coordinate="0.25" />
    <OutputPort id="4" parent="1" coordinate="0.5" />
    <InputPort id="5" parent="1" coordinate="0.75" />
    <OutputPort id="6" parent="1" coordinate="0.8333" />

    <Block id="7" inputPorts="0" outputPorts="1" />
    <OutputPort id="8" parent="7" coordinate="0.5" />
</root>

The position of each port depends on the port number and the total number of ports. The basic formula is:
coordinate(current, total) = (2 * current + 1) / (2 * total)

How do I get the value of current and total in my template?
Each Block, InputPort, and OutputPort tags have their own templates.
What I have tried involves use of global variables. However, I have found out that global variables cannot be reassigned globally in XSLT 1.0. We can reassign new values inside templates, but that is of no use in other templates or even in the same template called for a different tag. Here is my solution with global variables:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:variable name="inputPorts" value="0" />
  <xsl:variable name="outputPorts" value="0" />
  <xsl:variable name="currentInputPort" value="0" />
  <xsl:variable name="currentOutputPort" value="0" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="comment()" />
  <xsl:template match="Block">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="inputPorts">
        <xsl:value-of select="@inputPorts" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="outputPorts">
        <xsl:value-of select="@outputPorts" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="currentInputPort" value="0" />
      <xsl:variable name="currentOutputPort" value="0" />
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="inputPorts">
        <xsl:value-of select="@inputPorts" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="outputPorts">
        <xsl:value-of select="@outputPorts" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="InputPort">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="parent">
        <xsl:value-of select="@parent" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="coordinate">
        <xsl:value-of select="(2 * $currentInputPort + 1) div (2 * $inputPorts)" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:variable name="currentInputPort" select="$currentInputPort + 1" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="OutputPort">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="parent">
        <xsl:value-of select="@parent" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="coordinate">
        <xsl:value-of select="(2 * $currentOutputPort + 1) div (2 * $outputPorts)" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:variable name="currentOutputPort" select="$currentOutputPort + 1" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


Please edit your question and provide (1) a well-formed XML input example, (2) your current XSLT attempt and (3) the exact expected output (as code). we also need a better explanation what does the term "current" mean in your usage.

The formula you show for processing the "coordinate" does not produce the results you claim.

Does the order of ports within the block matter? You will find it difficult to keep a separate count for each type and  to restart the counts at each block.

For InputPort id="5" you show coordinate(1,2). Your formula (1 + 1) / 2 * 2 returns 0.5, not 0.75.  Some other values also do not match.

@y.arazim I have fixed the formula now. Also, current is zero based. Thank you for noting this.

@michael.hor257k yes, order of input ports matter. I actually have two types of input ports, which I did not mention in the problem. Same goes for output ports. However, order amongst input and output ports does not matter,

Sorry, that's not clear enough. Would it be alright to list all the input ports in a block first (in their original order), then list all the output ports (again, preserving their internal order)?  --- FYI, all counts in XSLT are 1-based.

@michael.hor257k The xml is not generated by me. Yes, it is possible to modify the xml to group similar ports. If possible, I want to avoid this.

@michael.hor257k I have edited the question as requested. Also, I have added comments on what current means.

If it is acceptable to output the ports of a block grouped by type, you could perform the transformation in a single pass:
XSLT 1.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k-in" match="InputPort" use="@parent" />
<xsl:key name="k-out" match="OutputPort" use="@parent" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Block">
            <xsl:variable name="inputPorts" select="@inputPorts" />
            <xsl:variable name="outputPorts" select="@outputPorts" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <!-- input ports -->
            <xsl:for-each select="key('k-in', @id)">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="numerator" select="2 * (position() - 1) + 1" />
                    <xsl:attribute name="coordinate">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$numerator div (2 * $inputPorts)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- output ports -->
            <xsl:for-each select="key('k-out', @id)">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="numerator" select="2 * (position() - 1) + 1" />
                    <xsl:attribute name="coordinate">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$numerator div (2 * $outputPorts)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Result
<root>
  <Block id="1" inputPorts="2" outputPorts="3"/>
  <InputPort id="3" parent="1" coordinate="0.25"/>
  <InputPort id="5" parent="1" coordinate="0.75"/>
  <OutputPort id="2" parent="1" coordinate="0.166666666666667"/>
  <OutputPort id="4" parent="1" coordinate="0.5"/>
  <OutputPort id="6" parent="1" coordinate="0.833333333333333"/>
  <Block id="7" inputPorts="0" outputPorts="1"/>
  <OutputPort id="8" parent="7" coordinate="0.5"/>
</root>


Tested this stylesheet now. Looks great. I initially thought that I have to sort the ports before using your stylesheet, but that was not required. As it is preserving the InputPort order and the OutputPort order, which is what is required, this is also an acceptable solution.

(edited)
Maybe something like this could work for you. It works in two passes in order to achieve the restart of numbering(s) for each block:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="ports" match="InputPort | OutputPort" use="@parent" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- pre-process -->
    <xsl:variable name="nested">
        <xsl:for-each select="Block">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('ports', @id)"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($nested)/Block">
            <xsl:variable name="inputPorts" select="@inputPorts" />
            <xsl:variable name="outputPorts" select="@outputPorts" />
            <!-- block -->
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <!-- ports -->
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:variable name="n">
                    <xsl:number/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="numerator" select="2 * ($n - 1) + 1" />
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="coordinate">
                         <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="self::InputPort">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$numerator div (2 * $inputPorts)"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="self::OutputPort">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$numerator div (2 * $outputPorts)"/>
                           </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

With your corrected XML input this returns:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <Block id="1" inputPorts="2" outputPorts="3"/>
   <OutputPort id="2" parent="1" coordinate="0.16666666666666666"/>
   <InputPort id="3" parent="1" coordinate="0.25"/>
   <OutputPort id="4" parent="1" coordinate="0.5"/>
   <InputPort id="5" parent="1" coordinate="0.75"/>
   <OutputPort id="6" parent="1" coordinate="0.8333333333333334"/>
   <Block id="7" inputPorts="0" outputPorts="1"/>
   <OutputPort id="8" parent="7" coordinate="0.5"/>
</root>


Thank you for your help. The code works correctly as desired. Can you also add an explanation on what exsl:node-set is?

@SunilShetye I am afraid it's a rather long story. In a nutshell it converts a result tree fragment to a node-set. This is necessary because only a very limited set of operations can be performed on a RTF. It is a well-known downside of XSLT 1.0 and practically every XSLT 1.0 processor supports an extension function to perform this conversion.
